# How can I pass a value from application.properties in @Scope and @Collection annotations?

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I want to prepare for a migration from Couchbase 6.X to 7.X. For this, I want to configure the scope and collection for my cluster. In the documentation of spring-data-couchbase, I saw that I just need to add @Scope and @Collection on my repository.
This configuration works:

```java
package xxx.couchbase;

import xxx.MyDocument;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.Collection;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.CouchbaseRepository;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
@Scope("_default")
@Collection("_default")
public interface MyDocumentRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<MyDocument, String> {
}
```

What I want to do:

```java
package xxx.couchbase;

import xxx.MyDocument;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.Collection;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.CouchbaseRepository;
import org.springframework.data.couchbase.repository.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
@Scope("${couchbase.scope}")
@Collection("${couchbase.collection}")
public interface MyDocumentRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<MyDocument, String> {
}
```

application.properties:

```
couchbase.scope=_default
couchbase.collection=_default
```

This latter configuration doesn't work, because the string value in the annotation is not parsed and is taken literally.
I'm working with Spring Boot version 2.7.3, spring-boot-starter-data-couchbase version 2.7.3.

Is there another way to pass the value from the application.properties to the annotations ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way for spring boot to populate arguments of an annotation with values from application.properties.

But you can populate variables from values in application.properties like this:

```
@Value("${scopeName}")
private String scopeName;

@Value("${collectionName}")
private String collectionName;
```

And then define your repository to extend DynamicProxyable

```
public interface AirportRepository extends CouchbaseRepository<Airport, String>, DynamicProxyable<AirportRepository>{...}
```

And then get a repository object with that scope and collection as the defaults:

```
List<Airport> airports = airportRepository.withScope(scopeName).withCollection(collectionName).findByName(iata);
```

see https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/4.4.6/reference/html/#couchbase.collections